# Laravel 4 - get json list one table with relations

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table `customers` and a table `orders`.
And I want to make an ajax call to get a list of all customers with name x and their orders.
I got the ajax function and my function to retrieve the customer looks like this:

```
$customers = Customer::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get()
            ->toJson();
return $customers;
```

With this I can only get all customers, can I modify this to get also their orders?
I think I could do it with join or is there any magic function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relationship: follow the link and create one to many relationship and use the relationship in your query.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

```
$customers = Customer::with('orders')
        ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();

return $customers->toJson();
```